# get package last release version with request like web service on github api

Tags: api, rest, github

exist any way to retrieve the package last version release on github api, i can't find any to it...

expented and output with:

```
current version: v1.1.0.0
```

Current documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/checks

Package to get the last release version from rquest api:
https://github.com/arcanisgk/BEH-Basic-Error-Handler

Answer (score 0):

**with javascript:**

```
let result = await GetVersion('https://api.github.com/repos/arcanisgk/BEH-Basic-Error-Handler/releases/latest');
console.log(result.tag_name);
```